# How can I use setTimeout method to refresh a jTable after "x" number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, reload, jquery-jtable

Here is what I've got:

```
 <body>
        <div id="TableContainer"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#TableContainer').jtable({
                    title: 'title',
                    actions: {
                        listAction: 'JSONServlet',
                    },
                    ajaxSettings: {
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        Id: {
                            key: true,
                            list: false
                        },
                        Tag: {
                            title: 'Tag',
                            width: '40%'
                        },
                        V: {
                            title: 'V',
                            width: '10%'
                        },
                        S: {
                            title: 'S',
                            width: '10%'
                        },
                        Timestamp: {
                            title: 'Timestamp',
                            width: '30%',
                            create: false,
                            edit: false
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('load');
      ///////     window.setTimeout("$('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('reload')", 100);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
```

I am using a [jTable](http://jtable.org/ApiReference#met-reload) and everything works fine besides my setTimeout method. In firebug it looks like it is able to make a request twice. Once being the normal request and another from my method I assume but after the second time there are no more requests.
I'm new to web development so if you could give me a quick explanation as to what I'm doing wrong that would help also.

Comment: if you are wanting it to refresh every x seconds then you need setInterval or another call to setTimeout in the the function that gets called by setTimeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are wanting it to refresh every x seconds then you need setInterval or another call to setTimeout in the the function that gets called by setTimeout

```
var timerID = setInterval("$('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('reload')", 100);
```

OR

```
var timerID = null;
function doReload() {
     $('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('reload');
     timerID = setTimeout(doReload,100);
}

doReload();
```

use `timerID` to save a reference to the timer and cancel the timer if needed, `clearTimeout(timerID)`, `clearInterval(timerID)`

Although you have it being called every 0.1 seconds, as the number is for milliseconds, so that is quite quick for doing ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` only fires once.

`setInterval` fires repeatedly until you call `clearInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (after 100ms):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){$('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('reload');}, 100);
```

Or this (every 100ms):

```
window.setInterval(function(){$('#DeviceTableContainer').jtable('reload');}, 100);
```